# What do the blue poison icons mean?

Tags: stone-story-rpg

While fighting Bolesh, the Cunning, the spider boss from the Caves of Fear location, it eventually gets blue poison symbols (in addition to the snowflake freeze icons from my attacks).  What do these mean and why are they being added?

[image: screenshot]